# Submitting form to admin-post.php Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've been trying to get a basic plugin to work and I have followed what seems to be the flow to get the form to post to admin-post.php.

However I seem to be going back and forth between the white screen of death, and the backend admin menu just flashing without giving any kind of error or message. The data does not get written to the database either.

This is my main plugin file

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test form
 */

function wp_meetings_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Meetings', 'Meetings', 'manage_options', 'wp_meetings', 'wp_meetings_form');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'wp_meetings_menu');

function wp_meetings_form() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Meetings</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Date and Time:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime"><br><br>2
            <label>Drop Down 1:</label>
            <select name="dropdown1">
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label>Drop Down 2:</label>
            <select name="dropdown2">
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label>Drop Down 3:</label>
            <select name="dropdown3">
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label>PDF File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="pdf_file"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="wp_meetings_submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

?>
```

and here is the function and hook in the functions.php file

```
add_action( 'admin_post_wp_meetings_submit', 'wp_meetings_submit' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_wp_meetings_submit', 'wp_meetings_submit' );

function wp_meetings_submit(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $datetime = $_POST['datetime'];
        $dropdown1 = $_POST['dropdown1'];
        $dropdown2 = $_POST['dropdown2'];
        $dropdown3 = $_POST['dropdown3'];
        $pdf_file = $_FILES['pdf_file']['name'];
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $pdf_path = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $pdf_file;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'], $pdf_path);
        $wpdb->insert(
            'wp_meetings',
            array(
                'datetime' => $datetime,
                'dropdown1' => $dropdown1,
                'dropdown2' => $dropdown2,
                'dropdown3' => $dropdown3,
                'pdf_file' => $pdf_file
            ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

All this manages to do is reload the plugins admin page without doing anything else or throwing any errors.. How is this supposed to be done exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The action is empty and loads the same page on submit which is the default behaviour for form without or empty action param.

Add **echo** admin_url( 'admin-post.php')

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks, I re-added the echo I forgot there and I'm just getting the white screen of death. I've also tried wrapping the admin_url() call in esc_url() and I get the same result.

Comment: I also enabled WP_DEBUG in the wp-config file and I am not getting a debug log in my files when re-creating the error.

Comment: You need to redirect somewhere after submitting the form. Also how did you create your database table?


I tested your code and modify it little to add redirect after submission. It works fine and writes into the database. I just created the DB manually and probably forgot to make the primary id auto-increment so it writes only once then threw error because of duplicate primary index in the error log.

If your database table is good, it should write.
https://codeshare.io/EBYQZK

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to get back to me, I actually figured it out the other day when you answered this. I came back to post my solution. I appreciate it again!

Answer (score 0):

There was a few misleading assumptions I made that had me making this harder than it needed to be.

There's no need to post to admin-post, keeping the action blank to submit to the current page is perfectly fine. Posting to admin-post is a really old methodology from what I can see.

I don't seem to need to add the url parameter that Wordpress automatically adds either.

The url parameters do not get placed in the url bar, leading me to believe it was not getting posted. (Assumption) Upon adding this to the file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Submit detected!";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

I was able to see the values were actually getting passed through successfully all along, just without traditional indicators.

Comment: The white screen of death is natural behaviour since you have not done anything after your logic in wp_meetings_submit() as @martin said add some redirect logic so you can get back to your settings page or something..

i.e `wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=wp_meetings'));`